# How to make a matrix squared by filling it with zeroes in C

Tags: c, matrix

I am currently trying to complete a m by n matrix (where m is greater than or equal to n) by filling it with columns of zeroes. The main problem is that my matrix is stored inside a double* and not a double**. So instead of my matrix looking like a 2d matrix it actually is a vector that sticks the rows of the matrix together in a single line.

Here is my poor attempt (I am quite new to the C programming language...)

```
void square_my_matrix(double* A, int n){//m is a global variable
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            if(i*m+j > j*m+n) continue;
            else A[i*m+j] = 0.0;
}

int main(){
    double* A;
    A = malloc(m*n*sizeof(*A));
    buildMatrix(); //this fills my matrix with some data
    printMatrix(m,n,A); //this prints my matrix in a 2d fashion to make it clearer

    if(m>n){
        A = realloc(A, m*m*sizeof(*A));
        square_my_matrix(A, n);
    }
    printMatrix(m,m,A);
}
```

My first `printMatrix` gives

```
1.00 1.00
1.00 3.00
1.00 5.00
1.00 7.00
```

And after calling `square_my_matrix` I expect (when calling `printMatrix` again)

```
1.00 1.00 0.00 0.00
1.00 3.00 0.00 0.00
1.00 5.00 0.00 0.00
1.00 7.00 0.00 0.00
```

but I get this instead

```
1.00 1.00 1.00 3.00
0.00 5.00 1.00 7.00
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

I probably messed up something obvious but I can't figure out what.

Thank you for your help

Comment: After you call `realloc()` you need to move everything to the correct row of the new size.

Comment: Is that what `square_my_matrix` is supposed to do?

Comment: maybe it would be logically simpler to call `malloc` and save the result into a new variable, `B`.  Then copy the data from A into B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Zeroing Added Memory (New Rows)**

If I understand what you are doing, you can originally initialize all values in `A` to `0` by using `calloc` instead of `malloc` (which will set all bytes zero). Then following your `realloc` you can use `memset()` to zero the new memory you have allocated. (if you need to zero the added columns, then see the 2nd part of this answer)

You can zero the new memory allocated with `realloc()` with, e.g.

```
double*A;
A = calloc (m * n, sizeof *A);
if (A == NULL) {          /* validate EVERY allocation */
    perror ("calloc-A");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

buildMatrix(); //this fills my matrix with some data
printMatrix(m,n,A); //this prints my matrix in a 2d fashion to make it clearer

if (m > n) {
    void *tmp = realloc (A, m * m * sizeof *A);  /* ALWAYS realloc with a temporary pointer */
    if (!tmp) {           /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("realloc-A");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    A = tmp;              /* assign reallocated block */
    /* set new memory zero */
    memset (A + m * n, 0, m * (m - n) * sizeof *A);
    
    // square_my_matrix(A, n);
}
printMatrix(m,m,A);
```

If you did want to use `square_my_matrix()`, then you would remove `memset()` above and use:

```
void square_my_matrix (double* A, int n)
{
    for (int i = n; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                A[i * m + j] = 0.0;
}
```

A short example putting it altogether and allowing you to choose between `memset()` by passing `-DWMEMSET` as a define, or by default using `square_my_matrix()`, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define m      10
#define nbegin  8

void square_my_matrix (double* A, int n)
{
    for (int i = n; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                A[i * m + j] = 0.0;
}

void printMatrix (int rows, int cols, double *A)
{
    /* check overflow in multiplication of rows * cols here */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf (" %3g", A[i * cols + j]);
                putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    int n = nbegin,
        v = 1;
    double *A;
    
    A = calloc (m * n, sizeof *A);
    if (A == NULL) {          /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("calloc-A");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // buildMatrix(); //this fills my matrix with some data
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            A[i * n + j] = v++;
    
    
    printMatrix (m,n,A); //this prints my matrix in a 2d fashion to make it clearer
    
    if (m > n) {
        /* ALWAYS realloc with a temporary pointer */
        void *tmp = realloc (A, m * m * sizeof *A);
        if (!tmp) {           /* validate EVERY allocation */
            perror ("realloc-A");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        A = tmp;              /* assign reallocated block */
#ifdef WMEMSET
        /* set new memory zero */
        memset (A + m * n, 0, m * (m - n) * sizeof *A);
#else
        square_my_matrix(A, n);
#endif
    }
    printMatrix (m,m,A);
    
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The output is the same regarless whether `WMEMSET` is defined:

```
$ ./bin/mxn2mm
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56
  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**Zeroing Only Last Columns**

If you need to zero the added columns instead of the rows, then you will need to manually copy the original rows to the rows of a newly allocated block and then free the original. To do so, you will have to change `square_my_matrix()` to take the address of the pointer (a pointer-to-pointer) rather than a simple pointer which will allow you to update where `A` points within your function. For example:

```
void square_my_matrix (double **A, int n)
{
    double *b = calloc (m * m, sizeof *b);
    if (!b) {
        perror ("calloc-b");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        memcpy (b + i * m, *A + i * n, n * sizeof **A);
    
    free (*A);
    *A = b;
}
```

In essence, you are writing the custom `realloc()`.

and then you would call the function as:

```
    square_my_matrix (&A, n);
```

**Example Output**

Then your output would be:

```
$ ./bin/mxn2mm
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56
  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   0   0
   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16   0   0
  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24   0   0
  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32   0   0
  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40   0   0
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48   0   0
  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56   0   0
  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64   0   0
  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72   0   0
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80   0   0
```

For completion, the updated `main()` in the example above would reduce to:

```
int main (void) {
    
    int n = nbegin,
        v = 1;
    double *A;
    
    A = calloc (m * n, sizeof *A);
    if (A == NULL) {          /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("calloc-A");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // buildMatrix(); //this fills my matrix with some data
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            A[i * n + j] = v++;
    
    printMatrix (m,n,A);
    if (m > n)
        square_my_matrix (&A, n);
    printMatrix (m,m,A);
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer ! My problem is now solved :)

Comment: Glad to help. It was an interesting problem with a couple of ways to look at it. I figure the zeroed columns is what you were looking for. Good luck with your coding!